# Calling MPI_Init more than once

Tags: python, pthreads, mpi

I understand that MPI_init can only be called more than once per executable instance. Can anyone clarify the limits of this language: ie:

1. I know multiple python exec on mpiexec can be run.
2. Is there anything like fork() or threads that can lead to something that qualifies? Is the criterion that they have to happen first and then invoke mpiexec?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the question whether you can add one or more processes by calling `MPI_init()` more than once?

Comment: `MPI_Init` initialises the environment needed to make MPI calls. It has little to do with `fork()` or `mpiexec`. At the point when `MPI_Init` is called all MPI instances/processes would have already started. You don't call it more than once simply because the initialisation process should only be done once and repeated calls may lead to errorneous behaviour.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity and I agree fork() was a red herring. As to Steve's question, I did not envision adding processes. One very simple example that might alert me to the potential dangers would be a repeated sequence of several MPI_Init and finalize calls on different code. I think Shawn covered that, though.

Comment: As background, I need to run two pieces of code that both have paired MPI_Init and finalize calls buried in them. I have no control about that code but but some control over the context in which I run them. I do not need to run them concurrently (although that might be a bonus). I assume, for reasons Shawn wrote about, that simply running both inside a simple program using mpiexec is not going to work. I was wondering if there is a clever way to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the easiest way would be to intercept the calls to `MPI_Init` and execute it only once. For C, MPI provides the PMPI Profiling Interface that allows you to override any MPI symbol and provides an additional PMPI symbol. E.g. you define a function `MPI_Init` and in that function, depending if it is called for the firs time, call `PMPI_Init`. The same (in reverse) for `MPI_Finalize`.

I am not sure about the most elegant way to do that in Python. I assume you could just hack into the python bindings or `LD_PRELOAD` a simple C library doing the *magic*.

All of that is just a workaround, that might have bad side effects. MPI Implementations advise you to not do much before an `MPI_Init`. The real solution would be fixing the code to use MPI appropriately.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to do this both ways you suggested. I agree it is a hack, but I was working with legacy code and this was something I had not thought of doing.